# Ubuntu always hangs while installing in dual boot HP laptop

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, 18.04, uefi, hp

I recently bought an HP 14s laptop with Windows 10, and want to dual boot with Ubuntu (16 or 18). Ubuntu 16.04 did got install (with touchpad and WiFi driver issue, which I can still try to fix later on). But the main problem is that whenever I boot into Ubuntu, it works fine for a few seconds, and then suddenly hangs. There is no option left other than force shutdown. If instead, I try to replace it with Ubuntu 18.04, then it also starts hanging, and that too during the installation phase.

(**UEFI** mode here BTW)

I have tried everything that I can think of. Tried turning off the secure boot access, tried booting in Legacy mode instead, but nothing works.

Can anyone shed some light as to what could be causing such erratic behaviour and what could I do to fix this? Would be highly grateful as I look forward to installing Ubuntu on my new laptop.

**EDIT:**

Methods that I have already tried:

1. Ubuntu 16.04.3, 16.04.6, and 18.04.3 - All of them causing the same problems.
2. Fresh downloaded ISO file on the destination computer instead of old laptop - Didn't work
3. Used "Startup Disk Creator" on Ubuntu (old laptop) as well as Rufus on Windows (New laptop) to create the USB disk - Didn't work
4. Computed and verified the checksum of ISO file after downloading as well as after writing to USB. No problems here - But new laptop still hangs on Ubuntu ('Try' mode as well as 'install' mode)
5. Enabling Legacy mode doesn't allow Windows to boot at all, so I guess that method isn't worth exploring too much. Anyways, Ubuntu hangs during installation in legacy mode too.
6. Enabling/disabling secure boot mode in BIOS settings doesn't make any difference.

On top of all that, the USB image created through whichever way (16, 18, Rufus or Startup Disk Creator) always works on my old laptop (Verified by going into trial mode of Ubuntu. Also, no WiFi/touchpad issue there), So I don't think the problem is with my methods of writing the ISO file onto the USB drive.

**FYI**: Windows 10 works perfectly, without any problem at all.

Comment: Does your laptop have an Nvidia card?

Comment: No, no graphic card

Comment: 1.When the Ubuntu session hangs can you switch to another tty with CTRL+ALT+F1(or F2-F6)

Comment: 2. If you can swtich to tty console, execute (as root or with sudo) `dmesg > log_dmesg_full.txt & dmesg -l err > log_dmesg_err.txt & cat /var/log/boot.log > log_boot_log.txt & cat /var/log/kern.log  > log_kern_log.txt & journalctl -m > log_journallog_full.txt && sync && mkdir logs && mv log_* logs` and include the logs here (use pastebin for the longer longs)

`

Comment: 3. TRY THIS FIRST: Before you login as user through the login greeter, press CTRL+ALT+F2 and login through that tty terminal that you will get switched to. Once there run the logging commands I wrote in (2) and with pastebinit (getit with `sudo apt update && apt-get install pastebinit ` ) you can post each log to pastebin by running `for f in log_*; do tail -c 1000 $f |  pastebinit -P ; done > links_pastebin` . You will just need to provide the output of links_pastebin here then.

Comment: Did you validate your download & especially write to install-media (ie. use the *check disc for errors* prior to install). If either download or write was imperfect, you'll be wasting your time, so the 120 secs this takes I think of as cheap insurance.  https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0  https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/i386/ch05s04.html *I can't find the page I really want*

Comment: @BarBar1234 I can only switch to tty console before everything hangs, and even when I do so, the tty also hangs after a few seconds.

Comment: @guiverc The download as well as the write was correct. I checked them with the checksum method. Also, the same USB image that was hanging in my new laptop is working correctly if I try to run it in my old laptop (Lenovo) when I go for "Try Ubuntu option".

Comment: using another machine to 'test' a thumb-drive only works if the hardware is identical, and same functions are used to ensure some packages are read with no squashfs errors checked... if you other 'test' didn't include the same options exactly (inc. install requiring same packages as same hardware modules used in both) it's invalid.   But heh I'm sure you checked `dmesg` for squashfs errors too...  The check media for defects is the easy option, far faster than the alternatives.

Comment: Hey @archity did you solve it? I'm having a similar problem - tried with 16, 18 and 20 LTS till now with all the circumstances similar to yours. I shall be waiting for an answer to this question.

Comment: @MayankM. No, I still haven't been able to. I'm at the mercy of VM and WSL to fulfill my Linux requirements, but other than that I have not been able to dual boot on my HP laptop yet. Do you also have the same exact model of HP as mine (HP 14s) ?

Comment: @archity yes I've the same laptop. And now I've also given up after a lot of Reasearch etc... There's no conclusive solution. All my attempts almost failed.